# Какие форматы шрифтов нужно подключать в @font-face?

Tags: css

Подключаю через @font-face шрифт:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "VAGWorldBold";
    src: url("../fonts/VAGWorldBold.woff2") format("woff2"),
         url("../fonts/VAGWorldBold.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/VAGWorldBold.otf") format("opentype");
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Какие еще форматы шрифтов нужно подключить? Или достаточно woff2, woff и otf?

Comment: http://xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/typographics/font-face-in-the-details там есть таблица соответствий, формат шрифта - операционная система

Comment: Там нет woff2. Этот формат не обязателен для подключения?

Comment: woff2 это вроде более компактный шрифт по сравнению с woff,  а больше не знаю о нем.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=woff http://caniuse.com/#search=woff2 http://caniuse.com/#search=otf http://caniuse.com/#search=ttf http://caniuse.com/#search=eot

Comment: Я уже разобрался, спасибо. Буду использовать шрифты, опираясь на информацию с caniuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно использовать WOFF и WOFF2, таким образом вы сможете подключить шрифты даже к ИЕ9. В OTF нет необходимости, его поддержка браузерами находится практически на таком же уровне, как и у WOFF.